# На каком уровне шифруется http?

Tags: http, tcp, osi

Шифруется весь http запрос, то есть, шифруется на уровне tcp или шифруется на уровне http и только контент, но не загловки?

Comment: Устанавливается tls-соединение и внутри него передаётся весь http

Comment: А что вы называете шифрованием? Если обрамление тела http вы называете шифром - то ответ - на последнем.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP не шифруется.
защищенным является HTTPS
при этом при запросе https://server/get/my/data?a=b

1. создается tls туннель до server (обычно на порт 443)
2. внутри туннеля обрабатываются стандартные http запросы. в данном случае GET /server/get/my/data?a=b

т.о. внешний наблюдатель будет знать только о самом факте соединения с server, но ни конкретные url ни заголовки ни какие-либо другие данные не увидит